# Ruby, how to find if a keyword from a list of keywords was the only one to appear in a string

Tags: ruby, string

I have list of key words, and i have a big string,. What i am interested in finding out is which keyword if any was the only one to appear in this string, so if more than one keyword from the list was in the string, then it gives nothing but if only 1 keyword from the list appeared i want to know that (how many times this single keyword was repeated doesn't matter). I am going to do this for multiple big strings.

Example as requested :

```
keywords=['cat','dog','mouse']

string1 = 'cat ate dog food'
string2 = 'dog chased cat'
string3 = 'my cat is chasing a mouse'
string4 = 'mouse ran away, mouse mouse mouse'

output for string1: false
output for string2: false
output for string3: false
output for string4: 'mouse'
```

Comment: give us an example, with desired output please:)

Comment: @sagarpandya82 done

Comment: Benchmark code here if anyone's interested: https://repl.it/EbZ5/1 There are so many variations that I wasn't sure which strings-keyword combos to use to make a fair test. Also you'll have to run it on your machine since repl.it won't load 'fruity'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have interpreted the question literally, that you are checking to see if each `keywords` element is a substring of the string, not a word in the string (e.g., "sandy" contains the keyword "and"). Moreover, I've assumed there are no upper-case letters in the string or any keyword (following, possibly, some pre-processing).

```
def just_one_match?(str, keywords)
  arr = keywords.lazy.select { |keyword| str.include?(keyword) }.first(2)
  (arr.size==1) ? arr.first : false
end

keywords = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']

just_one_match? 'dog pig elephant', keywords
  #=> "dog" 
just_one_match? 'dog chased cat', keywords
  #=> false 
just_one_match? 'cat dog mouse', keywords
  #=> false 
just_one_match? 'mouse ran away, mouse mouse mouse', keywords
  #=> "mouse" 
just_one_match? 'it was a three-legged pig?', keywords
  #=> false
```

[Enumerator::Lazy#lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-lazy) makes the enumerator [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select) lazy. That, combined with [Array#first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-first), causes the enumeration to terminate as soon as two matches are found. (In my third example above the enumeration stops after `cat` and `dog` have been found.) If two matches are not found either an empty array or an array of one element is returned.

Another way that terminates the enumeration when two matches have been found is to use [Enumerable#one?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F) and [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
def just_one_match?(str, keywords)
  return false unless keywords.one? { |keyword| str.include?(keyword) }
  keywords.find { |keyword| str.include?(keyword) }
end
```

Also (possibly the fastest),

```
def just_one_match?(str, keywords)
  found = false
  arr = keywords.select do |keyword|
    next unless str.include?(keyword)
    return false if found
    found = true
  end
  found ? arr.first : false
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def only_one(str, keywords)
  result = nil
  count = keywords.count { |k|
    result = k if str.include?(k)
  }
  count == 1 ? result : false
end
```

`Enumerable#count` will count how many times its block is truthy. The last expression of the block is a conditional assignment; it will produce `nil` if it is falsy, and the new value of `result` if truthy. `result` will always contain a truthy value here because all keywords are strings, and all strings are truthy. At the end, we just check whether there was a single

Comment: I have switched the accepted answer, because the other answer is more efficient.

Comment: That's fine. I upvoted him too. :)

Comment: It's not necessarily more efficient. That's an empirical question. For  one, lazy enumerators have a rep for being slower than their non-lazy counterparts.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: They *are* slower (currently), assuming the amount of processing is the same. But yours breaks early, which is an optimisation mine doesn't have. So yours should take much less time for long keyword lists, and data where most rows have two or more keywords. Mine will be faster where most data does, indeed, have only one or no keywords, and small keyword lists.

Comment: In my case the strings are long have a lot of keywords, and i have 22 keywords, so this optimization is an important addition ^_^.